# Uninstalling MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

I've removed MacVim from my `/Applications/` directory but in terminal when I type `vim` an error is displayed: `no such file or directory: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`
How do I go back to using the pre installed copy of vim?

Comment: This probably belongs on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the terminal type: `which vim`
That'll tell you what it's running when you type vim.
And if it's not `/usr/bin/vim` you're probably safe to delete it so it can find the pre installed version again.

Answer (score 12):

Try `brew uninstall macvim`.
It will help if MacVim was installed with brew.